# во всех подпапках создать файл с именем подпапки в которой он лежит в терминале линукс

Tags: linux, bash

во всех подпапках создать файл с именем подпапки в которой он лежит, и содержащий список файлов подпапки, в терминале линукс ?

Есть папка Музыка, в ней подпапки Киркоров, Пугачева ... (~250) папок,
в каждой подпапке свои подпапки года 2001..2019, в ней подпапки город, Москва, Питер и т.д

[image]

Если я сейчас зайду в папку Москва и в терминале запущу

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'for d; do ls -R > "$d/"${PWD##*/}".txt"; done' _ {} +
```

получу файл со списком файлов и именем Москва.txt
потом я в папке 2019 и Имя певца запускаю ту же команду, в итоге у меня в каждой папке несколько файлов Москва.txt, 2019.txt Ляпис Трубецкой.txt и т.д

Возможно ли сделать так что запустив только одну команду в папке Музыка я получил в каждой подпапке файл, один файл, содержащий список файлов в этой подпапке, в каждой подпапке с именем пути-названий подпапок.

например:

Музыка_Ляпис Трубецкой_2019_Москва.txt
 в папке
./Музыка/Ляпис Трубецкой/2019/Москва/

Музыка_Ляпис Трубецкой_2019_Питер.txt
 в папке
./Музыка/Ляпис Трубецкой/2019/Питер/

Comment: да, это возможно. пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] и впишите, что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: `find /music/ -mindepth 2 -type d -execdir sh -c 'a="{}"; awk -F/ "{print \"FOLDER:\" \$(NF-2)\"_\"\$(NF-1)\"_\"\$NF}" <<< "$PWD/${a/.\/}"; ls {};' \;` Проверьте если вывод корректный, то переведите вывод в файл `find /music/ -mindepth 2 -type d -execdir sh -c 'a="{}"; awk -F/ "{print \"FOLDER:\" \$(NF-2)\"_\"\$(NF-1)\"_\"\$NF}" <<< "$PWD/${a/.\/}" > {}/${a/.\/}.txt; ls {} >> {}/${a/.\/}.txt;' \;`

Comment: sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: awk не умеет мне кажется работать с пробелами в названии папок

Comment: Либо с русской локалью, попробуйте перед выполнением сделать `export LANG=C`

Comment: я всё в файл 1.sh и запускаю в папке в терминале sh 1.sh теперь не выдает ни какой ошибки но и файлов не создает. Пробовал и без  export LANG=C и ней, все равно файлов нет. То что в самом начале выдавал Syntax error я ошибся в написании пути.

Comment: Поменяйте параметр `-mindepth 2` на `-mindepth 3` запускайте из каталога музыка

Comment: не работает и так и так ни чего не происходит.

Answer (score 1):

Имеем:

```sh
/tmp/Music $ tree
```

```
.
├── A
│   └── 2019
│       └── a
│           ├── 1.txt
│           └── 2.txt
└── B
    └── 2019
        └── b
            ├── 1.txt
            └── 2.txt

6 directories, 4 files
```

Список папок:

```sh
find ../Music/ -path '../*/*/*/*' -type d
```

```
../Music/B/2019/b
../Music/A/2019/a
```

Дальше элементарно:

```sh
for d in $(find ../Music/ -path '../*/*/*/*' -type d)
do
    filebasename="$(echo "$d" | sed -e 's:^../::' -e 's:/:_:g' -e 's:$:.txt:')"
    filefullname="${d}/${filebasename}"
    ls "$d" | sed "/^$filebasename\$/d" > "$filefullname"
done
```

---

**EDIT:**  Для папок с пробелами (спасибо @PotroNik):

```
find ../Music/ -path '../*/*/*/*' -type d |
while read d
do
    filebasename="$(echo "$d" | sed -e 's:^../::' -e 's:/:_:g' -e 's:$:.txt:')"
    filefullname="${d}/${filebasename}"
    ls "$d" | sed "/^$filebasename\$/d" > "$filefullname"
done
```

Comment: папки с пробелами у автора вопроса, вероятнее всего использовать лучше цикл `while read d`

Comment: @PotroNik  Спасибо, добавил.

Comment: @PotroNik Спасибо

Comment: @Ainar-G, Спасибо

Comment: @КоляНебенемеда  Если ответ верен, отметьте его как верный, нажав галочку под числом голосов.

Comment: Следующая итерация для случая с переводами строк и другими специальными символами :) (И да, `while read` очень медленный по сравнению с `find | xargs`)

Comment: @0andriy  Там уже без перла не обойтись, КМК.